$\mathbb{CP}^1$ and the Riemann Sphere
Let $\mathbb{CP}^1$ be the complex projective line defined through the equivalence relation of lines passing through the origin on the vector space $\mathbb{C}^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\mathbb{R}^2$ be endowed with the Riemannian metric $\frac{4(dx^2+dy^2)}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}$. The latter is almost the Riemann sphere, only lacking the point at infinity. Now from my geometry class i know that the riemann sphere and $\mathbb{CP}^1$ are isometric. And the riemann sphere projected onto $\mathbb{R^2}$ has precisely the Riemann metric defined above.
My question is: what is the isometry of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ onto $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the metric defined above (minus point at infinity)?. Not only that what is the Riemann metric on $\mathbb{CP}^1$? I only know that there is a metric on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ namely just the angle between the lines of the equivalence relation, so  $$z,w \in \mathbb{CP}^1: d(z,w)=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\left| \langle z,w \rangle\right|}{|z|\cdot |w|}\right)$$
I don't understand how you extract a Riemannian metric onto $\mathbb{CP}^1$ from this metric.

View $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{C}$ by mapping $(x,y) &\mapsto z = x + iy$. For each $(z^0, z_1) \in \mathbb{C}^2$, let $$ [z_0,z_1] = { (tz_0,tz_1):\ \forall t \in \mathbb{C} } \in \mathbb{C}P^1. $$ The map \begin{align*} F: \mathbb{C}P\backslash{[0,1]} &\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\ [1,z] &\mapsto z \end{align*} is a smooth diffeomorphism. The Fubini-Study metric on $\mathbb{C}P^1$ is $$ F^\left(\frac{4|dz|^2}{(1+|z|^2)^2}\right) =  F^\left(\frac{4(dx^2+dy^2)}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}\right). $$
